# Fb EventHandler

Tags: c#, .net, firebird, firebird2.5

I have written a windows service in Visual Studio that uses the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient ADO.NET provider. My code is:

```
FbRemoteEvent revent = new FbRemoteEvent(fb);
revent.AddEvents(new string[] { "new_g" });

revent.RemoteEventCounts += new FbRemoteEventEventHandler (EventCounts); 

revent.QueueEvents();
```

I'm using FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient, added in reference FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.dll, but if I write FbRemoteEventEventHandler error appears.

Why? What should be done?

Comment: Please post the full error or exception you get, don't make us guess.

Answer (score 0):

if found also nothing and there was just the declaration in the object catalogue :/

```
public event System.EventHandler<FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbRemoteEventEventArgs> RemoteEventCounts
```

so please try this ...

```
FbRemoteEvent revent = new FbRemoteEvent(fb);
revent.AddEvents(new string[] { "new_g" });

revent.RemoteEventCounts += new EventHandler<FbRemoteEventEventArgs>(EventCounts); 

revent.QueueEvents();
```